# How to "Launch Couchbase Server" on Linux?

Tags: node.js, linux, couchbase, linux-mint

I am new to Couchbase so I was following this [tutorial](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2015/10/create-a-full-stack-app-using-node-js-couchbase-server/) regarding CEAN Fullstack (Couchbase, Express, Angular and Nodejs).

I downloaded the couchbase server for linux mint (deb 7) as the per the tutorial instructed, I also successfully installed and ran the couchbase as a service.

But this part got me confused, the 2nd paragraph under **Installing Couchbase Server** it says

> Install the file that you downloaded and **launch Couchbase Server**.  Upon first launch it should take you through a configuration wizard.  The wizard takes about two minutes to complete.

[image]

The tutorial does not define how to start/launch the server. I feel stupid for asking this but how do you launch the "PHP-myAdmin-like" couchbase server with the GUI and admin panels and everything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Quick Installation and Setup](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/getting-started/installing.html):

> #### Set up Couchbase Server Set up Couchbase Server when you start the Couchbase Web Console for the first time.
>
> (...)
>
> 1. Open a browser and navigate to http://hostname:8091/.
> 2. In the URL, hostname represents the name or IP address of the computer that hosts Couchbase Server. If Couchbase Server is running
>      locally, enter localhost for the host name.
>
> etc.